# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined in JEST while testing onChange event, anyone can help me in resolving this issue

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I started learning React & JEST framework, created a login page with 2 input control

**Login JSX:**

```
import React from 'react';
import es6BindAll from 'es6bindall';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props,context) {
        super(props,context);
        this.state = {
            userName: '',
            passWord: '',
            loginMsg : ''
        }
        es6BindAll(this,['txtOnChange','handleClick']);
    }
    txtOnChange(e){
        this.setState({
            loginMsg: ''
        });
        if (e.target.name === 'userName') {
            this.setState({
                userName: e.target.value
            });
        }
        else if (e.target.name === 'passWord') {
            this.setState({
                passWord: e.target.value
            });
        }
    }
    handleClick() {
        if(this.state.passWord === 'testing' && this.state.userName === 'username'){
            this.setState({
                loginMsg: 'Valid Login'
            });
        }else{
            this.setState({
                loginMsg: 'Invalid Login'
            });
        }
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <label> Username </label>
                    <input name="userName" id="userName" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" value={this.state.userName} onChange={this.txtOnChange} className="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <label> Password </label>
                    <input name="passWord" id="passWord" type="password" disabled={!this.state.userName} placeholder="Enter Password" onChange={this.txtOnChange} value={this.state.passWord} className="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <button className=' btn btn-default' disabled={!this.state.userName} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
                {this.state.loginMsg? ( 
                    <div className="row">
                        {this.state.loginMsg}  
                    </div>) :  null }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Test script files for Login component...
```

when i try to write a unit test  in **JEST** received an error as below,

```
Login-Test.jsx: 

jest.unmock('../Login.js');

import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import Login from '../Login.js';

describe('Login test', () => {
   it('renders the Login',() => {  

      const loginCmp = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Login />);
      expect(loginCmp).toBeDefined();
      var handleClick = jest.genMockFunction();

      var loginButton = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(loginCmp, 'button');

      TestUtils.Simulate.click(loginButton);    

      var inputCtrl =  TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(loginCmp, 'form-control')[0];

      TestUtils.Simulate.change(inputCtrl, { target: { value: 'username', name: 'userName' } })
      TestUtils.Simulate.change(inputCtrl, { target: { value: 'testing', name: 'passWord' } })

      loginCmp.setState({userName: 'username', passWord: 'testing'});        
      loginCmp.handleLoginClick();

   });
});
```

Also, I have simulated click event which is not been mocked properly. so please provide some suggestion to mock click and change event properly in JEST.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined at txtOnChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `es6bindall` might be the problem here – I have not used the package myself, but the above test appears to run fine when binding the functions manually.

Replace the following line:

```
es6BindAll(this,['txtOnChange','handleClick']);
```

with:

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
this.txtOnChange = this.txtOnChange.bind(this);
```

Also, looks like `loginCmp.handleLoginClick` should be `loginCmp.handleLoginClick`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. It really solved the problem, also i added 'es6bindall' in Package.json as below under jest,                                                                         "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "react",
      "fbjs",
      "react-dom",
      "react-addons-test-utils",
      "es6bindall"
    ] By adding this auto binding using es6bindall mocked successfully.

Comment: So, not an issue with es6bindall then?